# Kohana - where do you put AJAX scripts?

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am using [Kohana](http://kohanaphp.com/) but this question applies to Rails, CI, or any other MVC web development framework. Where is the best place to stick one's server side AJAX scripts?

I was *planning* on creating an Ajax_Controller and using a method/action per individual script.

For example, a login form on the home page **`index.php/home`** would send an XMLHttpRequest to **`index.php/ajax/login`**, and the edit profile form **`index.php/profile/edit`** would send an XMLHttpRequest to **`index.php/ajax/editprofile`**. What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Kohana but what I do in my framework is that AJAX scripts are controllers. I try to treat them as standalone controllers but in the end they are just controllers.

Answer (score 9):

I tend to put my ajax actions in the same controller as the non-ajax actions for any given model.

When I can, I try to use the same actions and only change the output type. Most tasks should have a non-ajax version anyway, so this tends to work quite well. Very handy for reducing logic duplication.

Comment: @Mario seems to agree to. Does that count as consensus?

Comment: indeed, don't change the controllers, the actions are the same. Just change your views (let AJAX views return JSON or something and "normal" views html)

Comment: Further on Pim's comment.. http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/request#is_ajax should help you out here.

Answer (score 7):

AJAX crosses all of the MVC boundaries.  That is, it doesn't go into just one of model, view or controller.

- Your AJAX scripts will be calling scripts on your site - so this would involve a section of your **controller** layer which you've created for the purpose.
- That controller in turn would access the database using the interface provided by your **model** layer, just as a non-AJAX request would.
- The data for the response back to the client may be packaged as JSON or XML or something.  Technically this is the task of your **view** layer, though if your application's definition of a view layer is nothing more than "an HTML templating system" rather than "processing and formatting anything that gets sent back to the client whether it's HTML or something else like XML" then your XML or JSON generation may need to go into a new little section of its own.

As for sending the scripts (Javascript files) themselves, this is probably going to be handled directly by the web server rather than from within your MVC framework.

Answer (score 5):

Do you make different controllers for GET and POST requests? I don't. In my opinion, JS requests shouldn't be dealt with differently either.

I personally see JS requests just like GET, POST or any other type of request. So if I have user-related JS-based actions, I simply create them in the user controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the AJAX (Javascript) scripts themselves, these should go into your public/js folder. However, if you mean the actions invoked by these AJAX requests, they should be treated as any other actions of the respective controllers. To be completely RESTful, you should be using a different format (json, xml, etc.) as return values for those actions.

Answer (score 2):

I am a noob, but based on my understanding, to achieve ajax with php mvc... thinking steps might be:

- change the definition/function of the existing php view layer from 'HTML template' into 'results formatting (XML,JSON etc..' -> results from relevant module, which then called by controller to output into AJAX object, then it means you need to write view layers into each particular class with formatting methods
- PHP module layer stays same
- build a Ajax router class with JS which stay the same structure which you route in your PHP
- build a ajax results handler class with JS  to handle the results got back from PHP controllers (XML JSON etc..), then from here do whatever user interactions you want, this will be called by above Ajax router class

So,

```
ajax router (send XMLhttprequest)
-> PHP controllers  C
-> PHP module -> PHP view results M
-> PHP controllers output results V
-> ajax results handle (into page)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a separate controller is a good idea.  I either organize my controllers by function and then actions by return type.

Additionally, when I'm using Pylons I can decorate an action with @jsonify and that will automatically take care of converting python objects to JSON.  Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep all my ajax requests in one controller, typically dispatching their requests through a shared model (that the non ajax controller also uses)

The main difference being the view that results via the ajax controller (html fragments, json data, etc) or the non-ajax controller (full pages)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it up as a general REST-api, and use RESTful conventions and URIs.
Example:

Instead of index.php/ajax/editprofile it could be a PUT request to index.php/api/profile/profilename.